# Create custom URL to make a custom search in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I create URL's like www.company.com/clientNameA, www.company.com/clientNameB so I can take the clientNameA or clientNameB and invoke a action in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routing configuration, try something like:

**As stated OP was looking for the following routing table:**

```
routes.MapRoute( 
          name: "Brand", 
          url: "{id}", 
          defaults: new { 
             controller = "Home", 
             action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { 
             controller = "Home", 
             action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional 
          });
```

**Alternative with separate controller/actions:**

***The route table***

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Home",
          url: "",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"
       });

routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Foo",
          url: "{client}",
          defaults: new { 
             controller = "Foo", 
             action = "YourAction", 
             client = UrlParameter.Optional 
          });

routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { 
             controller = "Home", 
             action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional 
          });
```

and add a controller:

***The controller***

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Foo/
    public ActionResult YourAction(string client)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I have the default route "url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" " this will not conflict?

Comment: Yes, but it seems like you want to break the {controller}/{action} logic. You could specify it for a specific controller to work this way: create a dedicated controller and add the routing above the default (routing mapping entries rely on the order in which they are added)

Comment: And how do I build the action? Index(string id) ? I get The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @Patrick: i updated the code a bit, this should work although you will lose you default home page (home/index) routing.

Comment: @Patrick: try not to name the target action "index", and don't put it in the "home" controller. this might lead to conflicts with the default parameters.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of to have, keeping the Home with the client as parameter

Comment: @Patrick: okay, i added the default home routing manually, it should work now.

Comment: I have done several tests and I think I found based on your answer: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Brand",
                url: "{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );   and then the Default.

Comment: @Patrick: That's great :) ... please mark mine as helpful and post your own answer if appropriate.

Comment: @Patrick: I left the old ones in it, just for the sake of information :)

Comment: Done! BTW, what is OP?

Comment: @Patrick: "Original Poster" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op

Comment: Hi Stefan, I run into a big problem with your solution, any request made to a Controller other then the Home-Page, redirects it to the Home-Page. For example, if I try to access the member area in www.company.com/Member, the system redirects to www.company.com

Comment: @Patrick: Hello again, I think it's best to post another question. Don't forget to include the entire route table.

Comment: Hi Stefan, ok thank you I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23613811/1480877