# Direct route to custom search with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I need to create a custom route with MVC to build a custom search:

Default Home's Index's Action:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And I would like to read a string like this:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Index(string name)
    {

        // call a service with the string name

        return View();
    }
```

For an URL like:

```
www.company.com/name
```

The problem is that I have this two routes but it's not working:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Name",
            url: "{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This way, any controller other then Home is redirected to Home, and if I switch the order, it can't find the Index Home Action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing for this. You can see the details about the package [here](http://attributerouting.net/#asp-net-mvc). After installing the attribute routing package. Now a days it is installed by default for MVC5 application. Change your action method as below:

```
[GET("{name}")]
public virtual ActionResult Index(string name)
{

    // call a service with the string name

    return View();
}
```

Here's a catch for the code above: 
    The router will send the requests without the name also to this action method. To avoid that, you can change it as below:

```
[GET("{name}")]
public virtual ActionResult Index2(string name)
{

    // call a service with the string name

    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I did not understand the issue without the name. I also need to open the Home-Page without the name, is it possible? I also have a WebApi, should I be aware of something using the package?

Comment: @Patrick if you dont pass anything as a name in the route (in this your default route) , the router hits the second action method by passing the null name parameter. The downside of this is that you will have to merge the default Index action with it. Instead of doing that, you can take the second approach. The attribute routing package works with Web API as well besides some advanced features mentioned on the site. If you install it for the MVC project, the web API does not have to use it. It can still use the regular routing.

Comment: Hi, but how it will find the Index2 Action if it's not in the route table?

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine. You don't have to put every single action in the route table. You can set the acceptable patterns using routing table. You can read more on routing here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: If I understand correctly the link you sent, I don't need Index2 because if name is null it will not generate any error in the action Index, correct?

Comment: You don't need it but having something like Index2(some other name than your default action) is cleaner if you are using attribute routing. It wont generate an error. I tested it. Feel free to test it at your end and if you get any issues, I will be happy to help and update the answer.

Comment: Sorry for all this questions but what happen to all other Controller/Actions, everything remain the same or do I have to put the route in all of them?

Comment: That is fine. Other controller actions can remain as they are. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have but it's not working, when I try a different controller like www.company.com/Contact I get redirected to www.company.com

Comment: In that case, contact gets treated as string. You need to put action next to contact. Do you want that pattern for all controllers? Your question does not say that.

Comment: I had to follow a different path to solve the problem, I will post the response